# Page loaded in div - Jquery dialog position only works the first time

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog

Im experiencing some strange problems and i cannot seem to solve it. Hopefully one of you can help me with this.

I am loading a page into a div (when a certain link is clicked)

Within this div (which is a different page) i show some data from my database. when clicked upon a jquery dialog opens and you can edit the entered data. When the form gets submitted the data is edited and the edited data is shown. I have written some code to position the dialog nexto the shown information. This works but only once...if i try to edit the data again the dialog opens in the default location (top left page) - if i do not load the page into a div - so load the page seperatly it works just fine every time.

I also found it very strange that i had to embed the jquery script in the index.php for it to work so not in the page i am including which uses the jquery. Now onto my code

```
<script>
 $(function(c) {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
       maxWidth:260,
        maxHeight: 85,
        width: 260,
        height: 85,

        show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
        },
        position: { 
        my: 'left, top',
        at: 'right, top',
        of: $('#opener')
        },
        hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
        }
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
    });

<body>
            <?php


            if(!empty($row['voornaam'])){
            ?>
            <div  id="dialog" >Naam<br>
                <p><form method="post"  id="naam"> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['voornaam'];?>" name="voornaam"  size="8"/> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['achternaam'];?>" name="achternaam"  size="8"/>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="opslaan" > </form> 
            </div>
        <button id="opener" border="0" color="white"> <?php echo $row['voornaam'] . " " . $row['achternaam']  ;?> &nbsp; <img src="edit.png" width="10" height="10"></button>

        <?php
        } ?>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    $(function(b) {
    $( "#naam" ).on('submit', function(){
    $(this).closest("#dialog").dialog("close");

          // gather the form data
          var data=$(this).serialize();
          // post data
          $.post('members.php', data , function(returnData){
                      // insert returned html 

                      $('#test').load('members.php')
          })

          return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
    });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: anyone who can give me a push in the right direction? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I put enclosed position `{}`  in `$( "#dialog" ).dialog({` it worked for some reason.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  You should include that you were able to fix it with your code but you don't know why that works.